# notificationClick to open downloads, but when activity is dead does nothing

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have some notifications, when I click one it opens downloads:

```
BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Intent dm = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        dm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctxt.startActivity(dm);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    FragmentActivity currentAct = getActivity();

    mgr = (DownloadManager) currentAct
            .getSystemService(currentAct.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    currentAct.registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

    currentAct.registerReceiver(onNotificationClick, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED));
}

    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    FragmentActivity currentAct = getActivity();
    currentAct.unregisterReceiver(onDownloadComplete);
    currentAct.unregisterReceiver(onNotificationClick);
}
```

problem is, while it's downloading user can go and kill the app, notification doesn't die (good) but on click don't open downloads either. ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the broadcastreceivers be part of your manifest, then send intents from broadcastreceiver to start activity and provide the specific click/download data in the intent.